# the checkbox values do not get cleared after post in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp

When I submit the form for the second time after a successful registration, the checkbox values of the previous post gets inserted. How do I clear the checkbox values after the form gets posted?

Comment: Perhaps the value of the check box is still present in the request. Have you tried reloading the page/ sendRedirect() ?

Comment: Can you explain in more details with example?